# Which constructive heuristics exist for the TSP?

Tags: traveling-salesman, heuristics

> A constructive heuristic is a type of heuristic method which starts with an empty solution and repeatedly extends the current solution until a complete solution is obtained. (Wikipedia)

Which constructive heuristics exist for the TSP? I know the nearest neighbour algorithm, the savings method and the Match Twice and Stitch (MTS). Which do furthermore exist?

Comment: you could add the best insertion algorithm, Christofides' algorithm, the sweep algorithm. Check out [this link](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/routing_options) for some more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These CH work:

- Nearest Neighbor
- First Fit, First Fit Decreasing, Strongest Fit, Strongest Fit Decreasing
- Cheapest Insertion, Regret Insertion
- Christofides algorithm (doesn't really deal well with extra constraints)
- Clarke-Wright algorithm (more for vanilla VRP, doesn't really deal well with extra constraints)

[Cook's book "In Pursuit of the Traveling Salesman"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691163529/in-pursuit-of-the-traveling-salesman) explains some of these very well.